# Fullcalendar: Fullcalendar.io dayClick and fc-more

Tags: fullcalendar

I've been trying to figure out how to trigger the 'click' action in the fc-more element by clicking in the fc-day element.

I think the best way to do so is by using dayClick in the options of the calendar, while it is initialized. The problem is how to find that element?, and click it. I do not know the generated 'id' for it, but the class is "fc-more."

Any suggestions are appreciated!.

Comment: Could you add some code samples that allow us to better understand your problem?

Comment: Check the answer, or u need more help?

Comment: Sorry, haven't had time to look at this further. Will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

> Possible, You need to hack **fullcalendar.js**

find a function starts with `setElement: function(el) {`. 
in FullCalendar v2.5.0 its on 3175th line just below the comments

```
// Sets the container element that the grid should render inside of.
// Does other DOM-related initializations.
```

you need to add else condition to this function as below

```
    el.on('mousedown', function(ev) {
                if (
                    !$(ev.target).is('.fc-event-container *, .fc-more') && // not an an event element, or "more.." link
                    !$(ev.target).closest('.fc-popover').length // not on a popover (like the "more.." events one)
                ) {
                    _this.dayMousedown(ev);
                }else{
                    alert('you clicked more');
                }
            });
```

you can add this line too in else to check if it is more only

```
if ($(ev.target).is('.fc-event-container *, .fc-more') )
```